# Integration, Parabolic Cylinder Function involved

Tags: integration, special-functions

Find

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}} e^{-sx}x^{\frac{b}{2}-1}D_{\nu}(k\sqrt{x})dx
$$

where

- $\nu<0$
- $k<0$
- $D_{\cdot}(\cdot)$ is the parabolic cylinder function
- $b>0$, $s>0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: Parameter in Cylinder function is  $v$ not $-v$ ?

Comment: Yes, but I need $\nu$ to be always negative. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{+}} e^{-sx}x^{\frac{b}{2}-1}D_{\nu}(k\sqrt{x})dx$ where $\nu<0$ if you wish